# Distribution with maximum 0-1 risk

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the 0-1 risk functional for binary classification:
$$L(g) = \mathbb{P}(g(X) \neq Y)$$
Where $g(\cdot), Y \in \{0, 1\}$   and $X, Y$ are random variables in the same probability space. Describe a distribution over $X, Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are not independent such that the minimum risk over all measurable $g$ is equal to $\min\{p, 1-p\}$ where $p = \mathbb{P}(Y = 1)$.

I know that the maximum minimum risk is $\min\{p, 1-p\}$ and is attained when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but I am having trouble coming up with an example where they are not independent. Intuitively I need some condition weaker than independence to hold, for example uncorrelatedness, but that hasn't helped me find an example yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let $X$ be Bernoulli(1/2) and let $Y$ be Bernoulli($p + (-1)^{X_i}\epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon$. If $p - \epsilon > 1/2$, then, regardless of what $X$ is, your best guess for $Y$ is still 1. (similar argument works for $p + \epsilon < 1/2$ for $0$).

By the way, uncorrelatedness for Bernoulli random variables implies independence, since the uncorrelatedness condition reduces to $P(X = 1, Y= 1) = P(X = 1) \cdot P(Y = 1)$, from which one can further show independence.

Comment: I see, so the idea is to identify a case where the best prediction is a constant, in which case the minimum loss reduces to the minimum class probability. Thanks!